# Getting HtmlDocument from string without using browser control

Tags: c#, browser, dom

I obtain a webpage's html code (as a string) using a WebClient.

However I want to turn it into an HtmlDocument object so I can use the DOM features this class offers. Currently the only way I know how to do it - is using a Browser control as follows:

```
            string pageHtml = client.DownloadString(url);

            browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

            browser.DocumentText = pageHtml;

            do
            {
                Application.DoEvents();

            } while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);

            return browser.Document;
```

Is there another way of doing it? I know there are other browser controls avaliable, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) .... For example:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var results = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("div")
    .Select(n => n.InnerText);
```

Comment: I will consider that, however I already have a lot of code which uses the HtmlDocument class, and I was more looking for something I could plug-in without needing to change everything.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but my repl is for others who come here like me

If you want to do it using code .NET [here is what you have to do](http://www.codewithasp.net/2015/10/get-htmldocument-from-string-in-c-sharp.html)

```
public System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument GetHtmlDocument(string html)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            browser.DocumentText = html;
            browser.Document.OpenNew(true);
            browser.Document.Write(html);
            browser.Refresh();
            return browser.Document;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Know it is an old topic, my solution:

```
public static class HtmlHelpr{

        public static HtmlDocument HtmlDocumentFromFile(this string PathToHtml){
            using(WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser()){            
                string s = File.ReadAllText(PathToHtml);
                wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                wb.DocumentText = s;
                var hd = wb.Document;
                hd.Write(s);
                return  hd;
            }
        }
    }
```